# Incrementing in foreach loop in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to collect data from a table for the past 3 years and was asked to create a new CSV file for each month data.I started creating a `SSIS` package for that using for each loop Container(with item enumerator) and I also created some variables like startdate, enddate, folderpath.

In FOREachloop I created data flow task there I want to fetch each months data which satisfies my startdate and Enddate condition and create a new CSV file for each month.

**ASK:**
I am not able to figure it out where I can increment my startdate and end date values. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please use "For loop container", if you have to execute your package for each month for three years.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more detail about your package than the somewhat hard to follow narrative, it is somewhat hard to answer specifically.

Anyway it sounds like you need a loop counter which you can add another variable then use an Execute SQL Task to increment it.  You can then either modify your startdate and enddate by the same Execute SQL Task and/or modify yet another variable for for month and use it in your SELECT statement in your dataflow.

If you post more detail of your package concerning the foreach loop, variables, and dataflow I and others will be able to provide more detail.